# Node.js + postgres Connection

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

In my node application i am connecting to a postgres sql in remote system

I have the following connection code:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://username:password@xxx.xxx.xx.xx:5432/dbname');
```

Its working fine.. but the following connection is not working:

```
// initialize database connection
var sequelize = new Sequelize(
config.dbname,
config.username,
config.password, {
    dialect: 'postgres',
    port:'5432'------------------->specified port here..
});
```

My config file:

```
{
    "server": {
        "port":        3000,
        "forks":        1,
        "siteUrl":      "http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:3000"
    },
    "dbpostgres": {
        "host":         "xxx.xx.xx.xx",        
        "username":     "username",
        "port"     :     5432,
        "password":     "password",        
        "dbname":       "dbname"
        }
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
"Error: connect ECONNREFUSED","    at errnoException (net.js:770:11)","
```

Please help me to solve this..Thanks in advance.....

}

Comment: Set the port configuration: `var sequelize =new Sequelize(..., {port: config.port, dialect: 'postgres'} `. Doesn't this work?

Comment: Thanks @bnuhero ..I tried that also but the same error. see my edited post..

Comment: I'm not sure whether the port should be an integer. So try this: `port: 5432`

Comment: I tried that also..no cange..

Comment: Is your database deployed on Heroku? If yes, add `protocol: null` to the configuration. FYI: [options](http://sequelizejs.com/docs/latest/usage#options)

Comment: No...Its not deployed in heroku..

Comment: You don't set the host in the configuration.

Comment: Then where i have to set??

Comment: `{host: 'xxx.xx.xx.xx', port: 5432, dialect: 'postgres'}`

Comment: Yes its works..thanks a lot..But why whats the reason???

Comment: If the host is not set, sequelize will connect localhost by default. But postgresql is not installed in your computer. Read this: [options](http://sequelizejs.com/docs/latest/usage#options)

Comment: @ bnuhero Thanks for your valuable time.